# Condition For 4th degree polynomial equation having positive roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials

Consider the biquadratic polynomial equation $\rho_0y^4+\rho_1y^3+\rho_2y^2+\rho_3y+\rho_4y=0$, where $\rho_0,\rho_1,\rho_2, \rho_4$ are positive and $\rho_3$ is negative. So by Descartes' rule of signs it has either two positive roots or no positive root.

> Now what is the necessary condition (on the coefficient $\rho_i, i=0,1,..4$ ) for which the above biquadratic equation must have two positive roots??

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no *the* necessary condition

Comment: Not that it matters much, but that's a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function), not a [biquadratic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biquadratic).

Comment: Technically, the necessary and sufficient condition is that the derivative $P'(y)=0$ has a positive root $\,a \gt 0\,$, and that $P(a) \lt 0\,$, but that's not going to translate nicely in term of the coefficients.

Comment: @dxiv I am not getting your point. can you explain in details?

Comment: @SAHEBPAL If $P$ has two positive roots then $P'$ must have a root between them by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), so the condition is necessary. If $P(a) \lt 0$ then $P$ changes sign between $0$ and $a$, and also between $a$ and $\infty$, therefore must have a root in each of the intervals by the [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), so the condition is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ be a quartic polynomial with real coefficients and $a>0$, $e>0$.

### Define:

### $\alpha = ba^{-3/4}e^{-1/4}$

### $\beta=ca^{-1/2}e^{-1/2}$

### $\gamma=da^{-1/4}e^{-3/4}$

### Then $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x>0$ the following conditions are sufficient for positivity:

- $\alpha>-\dfrac{\beta +2}{2}$ and $\gamma>-\dfrac{\beta +2}{2}$ for $\beta\leq6$
- $\alpha>-2\sqrt{\beta -2}$ and $\gamma>-2\sqrt{\beta -2}$ for $\beta>6$

Hope this help you.

Regards

Ric